# Ready to be taken

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

This is Hagen's replic from the Godfather:

> "Sollozzo finally got in touch and wants to sit down with us. A negotiator is arranging the details. That means we win. Sollozzo knows he's lost and he wants to get out with his life." Hagen paused. "Maybe he thought we were soft, ***ready to be taken***, because we didn't strike back.

Please, explain what `ready to be taken means` here.

Comment: You should take the time to learn all the possible ways 'take' can be used. One of the best English verbs :)

Answer (score 4):

It's not an idiom - it's just an alternate meaning of "take".  See the fourth or fifth entry under the word at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/taken?s=t):

> to seize or capture: to take an enemy town; to take a prisoner.
>
> to catch or get (fish, game, etc.), especially by killing: to take a dozen trout on a good afternoon.